# Trouble with my Fragment progression with config changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, android-configchanges

I'm currently facing a problem, I wanna handle correctly the rotation by not using the `configChange` in the `Manifest` as suggest by Google. But I don't really understand how it is possible to keep my progression after a rotation for example, specially when you add fragment to the ***`BackStack`***.

Does anyone know how or a `tutorial`, post, SMS, etc... explaining how to do that ?

Thanks in advance your answers ;)

Comment: You should take a look at this article, I've found it very useful: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html